# How to pause a Ridigbody2D in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pause

I would like to know how I can pause a rigidbody2D and resume it. I have tried a number of different ways and none have worked. I think the main issue is that when the game is paused, my rigidbody2D will be moving so I need to be able to pause the rigidbody2D, and when un - paused the rigidbody2D should continue moving as before.

This is the code I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour {


    private Rigidbody _rigidBody;
    void Awake () 
    {
        _rigidBody = Ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private Vector3 _pausedVelocity;
    private Vector3 _pausedAngularVelocity;

    public void OnMouseEnter() 
    {
        Debug.Log("Pause with velocity=" + _rigidBody.velocity + " & angularVelocity=" + _rigidBody.angularVelocity);
        _pausedVelocity = _rigidBody.velocity;
        _pausedAngularVelocity = _rigidBody.angularVelocity;
        _rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
    }

    public void OnMouseExit() 
    {
        _rigidBody.isKinematic = false;
        _rigidBody.velocity = _pausedVelocity;
        _rigidBody.angularVelocity = _pausedAngularVelocity;
        Debug.Log("Resume with velocity=" + _rigidBody.velocity + " & angularVelocity=" + _rigidBody.angularVelocity);
    }
}
```

Basically this code is attached to an empty with a collision2D component and when the mouse hovers over it, it prints pause, and when the mouse moves away, it prints play. So that all works, I just need to figure out how I can pause the rigidbody2D!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **pause all gameobjects** You could just set [Time.timeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) to  0

If you want to **pause just one gameobject**, on Pause you store the velocity and angular velocity and set [Rigidbody.isKinematic](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) to true and on Resume restore the original values.

```
public class PausableRigidbody : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody _rigidBody;
    void Awake () 
    {
        _rigidBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private Vector3 _pausedVelocity;
    private Vector3 _pausedAngularVelocity;

    public void Pause() 
    {
        Debug.Log("Pause with velocity=" + _rigidBody.velocity + " & angularVelocity=" + _rigidBody.angularVelocity);
        _pausedVelocity = _rigidBody.velocity;
        _pausedAngularVelocity = _rigidBody.angularVelocity;
        _rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
    }

    public void Resume() 
    {
        _rigidBody.isKinematic = false;
        _rigidBody.velocity = _pausedVelocity;
        _rigidBody.angularVelocity = _pausedAngularVelocity;
        Debug.Log("Resume with velocity=" + _rigidBody.velocity + " & angularVelocity=" + _rigidBody.angularVelocity);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

A `PausableRigidbody` instance can be called by a reference over a [SerializeField](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html), which can be filled by selecting a `PausingView` in the Unity Inspector and drag the Ball with the Script `PausableRigidbody` into Inspector, so that it looks like this:

[image: Unity Editor PausingView with serialized field PausableRigidbody]

```
public class PausingView : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private PausableRigidbody _pausableRigidbody;

    public void OnMouseEnter() 
    {
        _pausableRigidbody.Pause();
    }

    public void OnMouseExit() 
    {
        _pausableRigidbody.Resume();
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I implement that code into the code I have above?

Comment: replace Pause() with OnMouseEnter() and Resume() with OnMouseExit()

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, this script is on a separate object to the one I'm trying to pause. I've done what I can but I'm not sure what to do next as it is giving me an error. I've updated the code in my description to what I have now based on your code suggestion. And the error I have is: Assets/Scripts/Pause.cs(10,35): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent(System.Type)'

Comment: you can't run `Ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`, because the code can't decide, which Ball instance you want to stop.
You need a reference to the Ball instance.

Comment: Excuse my nooby question but how would I do that?

Comment: Google for a tutorial how to use SerializeField.

Comment: since I am in a good mood, I wrote an update, hope that helps, if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working without the SerializeField though. Thanks anyways!

Comment: `void OnMouseEnter() {
  ballVelocity = ball.rigidbody2D.velocity;
  ballAngularVelocity = ball.rigidbody2D.angularVelocity;
  ball.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
  image.enabled = !image.enabled;
  Paddle.isPaused = true;
 }
 
 void OnMouseExit() {
  ball.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
  ball.rigidbody2D.velocity = ballVelocity;
  ball.rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = ballAngularVelocity;
  image.enabled = !image.enabled;
  Paddle.isPaused = false;
 }`

Comment: That was my code, sorry doesnt look to good on here, try looking at in in mono or something.

Comment: I have a variable above that and I have simply dragged my ball onto it in the inspector, I cant explain that better! Hope you know what I mean!

Comment: okay, so the way I proposed in the update 1, just with a public ball instead of SerializeField, which is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a version that worked with Rigidbody2D... so here it is!

```
public class PausableRigidbody2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _pausedVelocity;
    private float _pausedAngularVelocity;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidBody2D;

    void Awake()
    {
        _rigidBody2D = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        Debug.Log("Pause with velocity=" + _rigidBody2D.velocity + " & angularVelocity=" + _rigidBody2D.angularVelocity);
        _pausedVelocity = _rigidBody2D.velocity;
        _pausedAngularVelocity = _rigidBody2D.angularVelocity;
        _rigidBody2D.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        _rigidBody2D.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
        _rigidBody2D.velocity = _pausedVelocity;
        _rigidBody2D.angularVelocity = _pausedAngularVelocity;
        Debug.Log("Resume with velocity=" + _rigidBody2D.velocity + " &    angularVelocity=" + _rigidBody2D.angularVelocity);
    }
}
```